# BigInteger in Properties.Settings.Default

Tags: c#, visual-studio, settings

I'm trying to get a BigInteger value to be persistent after the application closes. I also need to write to it after the application is done running.

Unfortunately when I select the System.Numerics namespace from Browse under the Properties -> Settings menu in Visual Studio, it doesn't give me anything I can select to store this value.

Is there another way I can store my BigInteger without creating another file to store it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save it as a string and do a BigInteger.Parse(string);